# Python threading and sockets

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to communicate with an instrument (Newport XPS D) via sockets.

Basically, I need two instances of my controller interface since the XPS only works with blocking sockets. One instance will be used for sending move command, the other for position polling.

There is something that I clearly don't get in how threads works since when I launch the program in two windows terminals (one handling polling, the other the move) it works juste fine, but when I start both interfaces in different threads in the same terminal, I get a busy socket error (I have checked that the thread IDs are different).

to clarify this is the code that crashes :

```
from XPS_unified import LTPXPS
import time
from threading import Thread, Timer

class my_indep_XPS(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.this_xps = LTPXPS(xps_version="D")
        self.timer = None
        self.stopped = False
        self.polling = False
        .
        .
        .
    def run(self):
        print(f"Thread #{self.ident}")
        if self.polling:
            for _ in range(2 * 60 * 2):
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(self.this_xps.get_position("Tx"))
        else:
            self.move(00)
[...]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xps_pos_th = my_indep_XPS()
    xps_pos_th.toggle_polling()
    xps_pos_th.start()
    xps_mov_th = my_indep_XPS()

    time.sleep(5)
    print("move start")
    xps_mov_th.start()
```

Comment: Python has `GIL` ([Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)) and it doesn't run threads at the same time. If one thread runs and blocks process then other has to wait. And maybe this blocks all your code. Maybe use module [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). BTW when you run in separated windows then system runs two processes, not two threads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I thought the GIL locked shared objects, here I have two instances albeit from the same class talking to the same instrument. So I don't get why one should be locked. Furthermore, the second object isn't locked, it does the "move" but the socket I am using says it is busy...